# WCF trace file keeps getting corrupted?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis, trace

I enabled message tracing on a WCF service. it traces a couple of messages and then it stops, when I try to open the trace in TraceViwer it gives me an error on the last message that got logged, or doesn't even open the file duo to different error everytime.

I can't even delete the corrupt file unless i run a resetiis since the file is being used!

here is my trace config.

```
<system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
                <listeners>
                    <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
                        <filter type="" />
                    </add>
                    <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
                        <filter type="" />
                    </add>
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add initializeData="C:\Logs\Web_messages.svclog"
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
              name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
                <filter type="" />
            </add>
        </sharedListeners>
    </system.diagnostics>

<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
          logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
    </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Per John's answer, you can use [Trace.AutoFlush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.autoflush.aspx) to flush the file after every write.  Something along the lines of [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) ...

```
<system.diagnostics>
   <sources>
       <source name="UserTraceSource" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing" >
          <listeners>
              <add name="xml"
                 type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                 initializeData="C:\logs\UserTraces.svclog" />
          </listeners>
       </source>
   </sources>
   <trace autoflush="true" /> 
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Hah! I didn't know about that!

Comment: John, that makes my day ... maybe my week! :)

Answer (score 1):

Is the service still running? Then the problem may simply be that the file has not been flushed yet.